# What I'm doing wrong in reset Cell value excel

Tags: vba, excel

As I'm, deeply new to excel programming I figure out a macro that help me validate cells and set cells to false if the value in another cell do not allow it

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Range("W" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Locked = False
Range("Y" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Locked = False
Range("Z" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Locked = False
Range("C" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Locked = False
If Range("U" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = "Controlled Good" Then
Range("W" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Locked = True
End If
```

But I want to reset the value of the none wanted cell back to empty , so I tried

```
 If Range("U" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = "Controlled Good" Then
Range("W" & (ActiveCell.Row)).value=""
Range("W" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Locked = True
```

But I'm receiving an error , what I'm doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: what happens when you change all ActiveCell.Row to Target.Row ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640) will get you started...

Comment: @ChicagoExcelUser Hi, same error witch is : Method 'Locked ' of object 'Range' failed

Comment: @SiddharthRout  this seens to work ! I will verify it and post it as an resolved once Im 100% sure it's working  Application.EnableEvents = False
Range("W" & (Target.Row)).Value = ""
Application.EnableEvents = True

Comment: @napi15: Good job! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 With ActiveSheet
        .Unprotect

.Range("W" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Locked = False
.Range("Y" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Locked = False
.Range("Z" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Locked = False
.Range("C" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Locked = False
If .Range("U" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = "Controlled Good" Then
.Range("W" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = ""
.Range("W" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Locked = True
End IF
        .Protect

    End With


End If
```

Comment: Yup !  I discovered that in fact I must shutdown the application event like this Application.EnableEvents = False
Range("W" & (Target.Row)).Value = ""
Application.EnableEvents = True

Comment: That makes sense. It will keep looping otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go  :) 
this worked too

```
    If Range("U" & (Target.Row)).Value = "Controlled Good" Then
Range("W" & (Target.Row)).Locked = True
 Application.EnableEvents = False
Range("W" & (Target.Row)).Value = ""
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```

thanks to [MS Excel crashes when vba code runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640)